# GWT or Liferay or just Tomcat: how to initiate update from server-side?

Tags: events, gwt, liferay, server-side

Is it possible to initiate the update of a portlet or web GUI object from the side of server? For example if a chat board is updated on the server how is it possible to ask all web clients to redraw it's contents?

I know that it is possible to query periodically from the client side, but I am interested in initiation namely from server side.

Interested technologies are GWT (Google Web Toolkit), GAE (Google App Engine) and Liferay (Portal server).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look for http://www.icepush.org/product/icepush-GWT.html page for IcePush solution to this problem. If you're enough familiar with GWT you'll find all the required information on their wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the GAE Channel API 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/